# Cannot figure out while loop

Tags: r, vector, while-loop

I am trying to create a while loop in R, with the goal of having a user input a number, having the code print the corresponding entry based on the numeric position it has in the vector, continuing to offer another selection from the menu, and then breaking the loop if 6 is entered. I can get it to provide the right output in terms of the number that entered, but then it doesn't go back through the loop. (I made edits to the code based on comments below, but it still won't work the way I need it to)

```
menu <- "MENU: \n1. Science Fiction \n2. Computers and Technology \n3. Cooking \n4. Business \n5. Comics \n6. Exit"

menuV <- c("You selected Science Fiction. This is a fun topic.",
           "You selected Computers and Technology. This is a complex topic.",
           "You selected Cooking. This is a passionate topic.",
           "You selected Business. This is a serious topic.",
           "You selected Comics. This is an entertaining topic.")

x <- readline(prompt=paste(menu, "Please select an item from the menu: "))
x <- as.numeric(x)

while (x != 6){
  if(x >= 1 & x <= 7){
    print(menuV[x])
  } else if(x < 1 | x > 7) {
    print("Invalid entry. Please try again.")
  } else {
    print("You exited the menu.")
    break
  }
}
```

`

Comment: Did you meant `menuV[x]` instead of `menuV(x)` as `menuV` is not a function and 'x' seems to be an index to extract the corresponding element from `menuV` vector

Comment: I did try that, but it doesn't resolve the issue that I noted.

Comment: Your readline is also having trouble `x <- readline(prompt = paste(menu, "Please select an item from the menu: "))`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Also, why do you need a `while` loop.  It can be a `switch` or `if/else if/else`.  If you note the condition, whenever you select x not equal to 6, it will go as infinite loop

Comment: Unfortunately, the while loop is a requirement for the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following work?

```
menu <- "MENU: \n1. Science Fiction \n2. Computers and Technology \n3. Cooking \n4. Business \n5. Comics \n6. Exit"

menuV <- c("You selected Science Fiction. This is a fun topic.",
           "You selected Computers and Technology. This is a complex topic.",
           "You selected Cooking. This is a passionate topic.",
           "You selected Business. This is a serious topic.",
           "You selected Comics. This is an entertaining topic.")

x <- readline(prompt = paste(menu, "Please select an item from the menu: "))

x <- as.numeric(x)


while (is.numeric(x)) {
  if(x >= 1 & x <= 5){
    print(menuV[x])
    x <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = paste(menu, "Please select an item from the menu: ")))
  } else if(x < 1 | x >= 7) {
    print("Invalid entry. Please try again.")
    x <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = paste(menu, "Please select an item from the menu: ")))
  } else {
    print("You exited the menu.")
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a response! This does not accomplish what I'm needing. It still won't continue to loop through offering the menu selection/input after each input, and does not provide a message when 6 is entered (i.e. "You have exited the menu") or break the loop.

Comment: @MameGannon-Luiz: Ok now I think I understood what the loop should do, please see my updated answer.

Comment: This is SO CLOSE! It does break, and do all of the other requirements, with the exception of the string printing prior to breaking.

Comment: Does it print the exit string for you?

Comment: No sure, it doesn't, because we start with `while(x != 6)`. I just noticed myself ;)

Comment: Currently wondering what rock I should go hide under

Comment: I now changed the while statement to `is.numeric(x)` but this makes the whole `while` part kinda strange, since we are not running through numbers as in a classic  `while` example.